# How to change the dependency at runtime using the flutter injectable library?

Tags: flutter, dependency-injection, dio, injectable

I am developing a flutter application that uses [injectable](https://pub.dev/packages/injectable) and [get_it](https://pub.dev/packages/get_it) libraries.

And I have a [Dio](https://pub.dev/packages/dio) reference that contains Auth token which is getting from the LocaleStorage service. When I change it at runtime it is not getting updated. Because of it I am getting the unauthorized user error from the API service.

Here is the my module ⤵️

```
@module
abstract class NetworkingModule {

  Dio getDio(UserModelLocalStorageService localStorageService) {
    final Dio dio = Dio()
      ..interceptors.addAll([
        if (!kReleaseMode) PrettyDioLogger(requestBody: true, requestHeader: true),
      ]);
    dio.options.headers["device-id"] = "1uazj1234";
    dio.options.headers["Authorization"] = localStorageService.getAccessToken();
    return dio;
  }

  @lazySingleton
  AuthApiService getCharacterListApiService(Dio dio, AppConfig appConfig) =>
      AuthApiService(dio, baseUrl: appConfig.baseUrl);
  
}
```

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this problem as follows ⤵️

```
final Dio dio = Dio();
dio.interceptors.add(
  InterceptorsWrapper(
    onRequest: (options, interceptor) async {
      final token = localStorageService.getAccessToken().toBearer();
      options.headers["Authorization"] = token;
      interceptor.next(options);
    },
    onError: (e, interceptor) async {
      // do something here if call fails, for example token refresh if it is expired
    },
  ),
);
```

Kudos to [@martirius](https://github.com/Milad-Akarie/injectable/issues/360)  for the solution